# How to retrieve a specific record from the database based on the value selected using a selection box?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, sequelize.js

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I am trying to retrieve a specific record from the database based on the value selected using a selection box.

Below is the console error

```
  GET /api/GetStats1?playerNumber=2 404
```

**Database table**

```
UserTeamsGamesStats Table

id: (int Primary Key)
playerNumber: (int) 
name:(varchar)
```

Below is my function which is executed once the user selects a value from the selection box.

```
handleChangePlayerNumber = e => {
   e.preventDefault();      

   var todoId = document.getElementById('todoId').value;
   resultElement.innerHTML = '';

   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/GetStats1', {
     params: {
         playerNumber: todoId
       },    
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);

    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    });

}
```

Below is the frontend selection box

```
        <select className='form-control'
          id="todoId"
          onChange={this.handleChangePlayerNumber}>

          <option selected='defaultValue' hidden='hidden'>
          Choose a Player by their kit number
          </option>


          <option value=2>2</option>


        </select>
```

**Backend NodeJS**

```
router.get('/GetStats1', async function(req, res) {

  const findUsers = await UserTeamsGamesStats.findOne({
    where: {
      gamePlayed: 0
    }
  });

  if (findUsers) {
   res.json(findUsers);
  }
  else{
    console.log('Cant find user stats');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the correct playerNumber from the query parameters. So, your findUsers call would look like this:

```
const findUsers = await UserTeamsGamesStats.findOne({
  where: {
    playerNumber: req.query.playerNumber
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `axios` is sending a GET request with `playerNumber` as param, you should be able to get your value in backend with `req.query.playerNumber` :

```
function(req, res) {
  { playerNumber } = req.query;

  const findUsers = await UserTeamsGamesStats.findOne({
    where: { playerNumber }
  });

}
```

Not sure about `gamePlayed` so I ignored it